# Finding the x and y values of a sprite in pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have a sprite, named Player and when it collides with another sprite, named Powerup, it will launch the sprite Player in the negative y direction up 700 pixels.

After the sprite Player has launched itself up 700 pixels I want a sound to play, however to do this I need to find a way to check whether the sprite Player has finished being launched up 700 pixels.

Basically something like this:

```
if sprite_player collides with sprite_powerup:
     sprite_playerYcoordbeforepowerup = previous_Y
     launch_player_up_700pixels
     then check
if sprite_playercurrentYcoord - previous_Y == 700:
     playSound()
```

Is there something similar to the function pygame.mouse.get_pos() which returns the position of the mouse cursor, that instead returns the x and y values of the sprite? If not, how would I go about doing this?

Sorry if this was worded badly, hope it's readable :)

Comment: Do you have a class or other structure that contains the current position? What does it look like?

Comment: Please show us a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), then we can give you proper tips about how to implement this behavior in your game.

Comment: We've got no clue how your classes and objects look like, but if you use [pygame sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), then they must have at least a [`pygame.Rect`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) attribute which contains the position. You can use one of the rect attributes to get the position, for example `self.rect.y` or `self.rect.top`.

Comment: @skrx: of course that's only half of the answer (though it's a fairly important half).

Answer (score 1):

your should use some rendition of an "islaunched" variable, to tell the system whether the player has just been launched, but would reset at the next iteration of the loop.

Alternatively, you could simply play the sound within the action loop, after the change in y (although not if motion is based off velocity). By this i mean that you would most likely simply teleport the player 700px upwards, in which case a delay between action and sound would be inconsequential, and would quite possible detract from the gameplay.